# Sending commands via I2C to PIC16F1503 using Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: c#, i2c, windows-iot-core-10

**Scenario**

I want to communicate with a PIC16F1503 controller using C# while running as an UWP app on a Raspberry Pi using Windows 10 IoT Core.

It seems that my source detects the controller using `I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(...)`. But if I try to send the "Servo1" command `0x01` via:

```
pic16f1503.Write(new byte[] { COMMANDO_SERVO_1 });
pic16f1503.Write(data.ToArray());
```

Nothing happens. I (hopefully) enabled the "Servo1" with:

```
private void WriteConfiguration()
{
    // Create configuration mask.
    byte config = 0;

    // Enable servo 1
    config |= 1;

    // Enable servo 2
    config |= 0 << 1;

    // Enable lights
     config |= 0 << 2;

     // Light mode
     config |= 0 << 3;

    // Light on
    config |= 0 << 4;

    // Write configuration to device.
    pic16f1503.Write(new byte[] { COMMAND_CONFIG});
    pic16f1503.Write(new byte[] { config });
}
```

**Full source**

[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/tscholze/825eb8904fe84db27283ffd88360b751)

Does somebody know further tutorials or new "entry" points to get along with C# und this mc? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you set correct I2C address via `new I2cConnectionSettings(I2C_Address); // set the I2C address of PIC16F1503` otherwise you will get "Slave address was not acknowledged" exception at  `pic16f1503.Write(new byte[] { COMMANDO_SERVO_1 });` when you debugging.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Yes - I think so. I updated the post with a GitHub gist link to the class. https://gist.github.com/tscholze/825eb8904fe84db27283ffd88360b751

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send several bytes from Raspberry Pi to PIC16F1503 via I2C and I get them via debugging your code: 1, 1, 1, 1-43-7-0-0, 1.

But they seems not all match what you want to send actually because I found a problem in your WriteByte function like:

(You are trying to change a value-type variable: `byte[] data`. Refer to "[Passing Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-value-type-parameters)")

```
private void WriteByte(byte command, byte[] data)
{
    data.ToList().Insert(0, command);
    data.ToArray();
    pic16f1503.Write(data);
}
```

I edit above function to this:

```
private void WriteByte(byte command, byte[] data)
{
    var sendData = data.ToList();
    sendData.Insert(0, command);
    pic16f1503.Write(sendData.ToArray());
}
```

Then send datas: 0-1, 0-1, 1, 1-43-7-0-0, 0-1

Little issue when print the `int` array.

Edit this line: `Debug.WriteLine($"PIC16F1503 - SetDegrees to {ms} start.\nData: {data}");`

To this in order to print the right format data:

```
        Debug.WriteLine($"PIC16F1503 - SetDegrees to {ms} start.\n");
        Debug.WriteLine("Data: ");
        foreach (var element in data)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(element);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("\n");
```

After that you will send right data to PIC16F1503. If still not working please check two devices I2C speed match or not. And hardware pins connection correct or not.

Comment: Thank you for your help!